# Windows Script Error in Vue-CLI

Tags: vuejs2, windows-scripting, vue-cli

I have switched to Vue.js. I created a new project in Vue CLI. I am getting an error from **Windows Script Host** with source error : **"Microsoft JScript compilation error on Line 1469"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tldr; Make sure your path is pointing to the Vue binary, not Vue.js

Very late, but for those stumbling upon this I think I might have the answer, which I've inferred from this [comment](https://github.com/javascriptair/site/issues/98#issuecomment-404420108). Basically the issue is that Windows is trying to run a Javascript file when it should be running a binary; Windows is trying to run "vue.js" when it should be running "vue". When I typed `vue --version` and tried to run a globally installed version of vue, I would get the aforementioned error.

[image: Windows JScript Error]

To fix this I checked my path (make sure you know how to edit this before continuing) and noticed that it pointed to a bin folder (which commonly holds binary files). However, the only file in the folder was "vue.js".

[image: Incorrect path to Vue Cli]

After a bit of digging I found the vue binary to be in `C:\Users\dan\AppData\Roaming\npm`, not `C:\Users\dan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin`. After changing the path to the folder with the binary file, everything works!

[image: Working Vue CLI]